# how to stay same cell after hit enter and move cell value to down

Tags: excel, vba

I need to stay at the same cell in the excel sheet and copy the cell value to down after hitting enter. need to keep the most recent value at the top and shift one by one down(the red arrow shows the current cell and the green arrow shows the most recent value). is there any way to do this with VBA programming?

[image]

Comment: Formula will not do this.  As far as coding something in vba, what have you tried?

Comment: That's a horrible data entry method and goes against the grain of how Excel works. You can write code to do this, but your life would be a lot easier if you just followed the standard convention of adding new data at the bottom.

Comment: Why not have the top 5 rows to collect the most recent data that is added at the bottom?

Comment: Trying to write a VBA script with stack operation.

Answer (score -1):

If you add this code to the Worksheet_Activate() event procedure

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Application.MoveAfterReturn = False
End Sub
```

so that the active cell will not change after data entry then you could code the *Worksheet_Change()* event for your data-entry tab as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then
        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            Target.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

and also add the code below the Worksheet_Deactivate() procedure

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Application.MoveAfterReturn = True
End Sub
```

so that the normal active-cell-move-on-Enter behaviour is restored on other sheets.

Comment: you do not need the full workbook setting.  Just add `Target.Select` inside your If and it should return to that cell.

Comment: @scott Not sure, but won't the insert move the Target range reference, and the ActiveCell?.  If so, use `Me.Cells(2, 1).Select` after the insert

Comment: @chrisneilsen maybe, but then we just do `Range("A2").Select`

Comment: @ScottCraner - thanks - the syntax would actually need to be Target.Offset(-1).Select, since the Insert moves it, but I believe in avoiding Select in code whenever possible.

Comment: @SpectralInstance, all 3 variations of the Select would work, it just a matter of style.   As for avoiding Select I agree in general,  but when the aim is to control the selected cell it's fine.  Using a global option that affects every cell is IMHO, excessive

Comment: @chrisneilsen - ok, I've updated the answer to limit the global option to the sheet in question - with more data entry I think the Insert will get slower and slower, and I don't believe having the Active cell move 'to and fro' will do anything for the efficiency of what is already an ugly procedure.